# Debugging cache in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, devise

After logging in with facebook (with devise and omniauth), I'm having an issue that I think might be a cache issue.

These are the steps that make it happen:

- Log out
- Go to /about
- Go to /, login, and get redirected to /
- Go to /about

At this point, the page shows as if I were not logged in. Then, if I reload the page with f5, it shows as if I were logged in (sometimes I have to press f5 a lot of times. Ctrl + f5 won't help)

I'm not sure how to debug this. It might be just the browser cache (I'm using firefox, in ubuntu), but even then, shouldn't my application be in control of that?

Any ideas on how to debug this?

**UPDATE**

Ok this is only getting weirder. Now if I keep pressing f5, it randomly shows me as logged in or not logged in. This can't be a cache issue.

I don't know if this matters, but I'm using mongoid_session_store-rails3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Delete cookies and cache
- Drop both collections
- Restart nginx